# What does うい mean?

Tags: words

Is the term a form of chat slang meaning yes?

Comment: can you copy paste the chat you saw this in??

Comment: http://getnews.jp/archives/78110

Comment: I would give @nhahtdh 's comment more than plus 1 if I could. Learned something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just another humorous way of saying "yeah" or "okay". It's probably from either French *oui* or [うっす/うぃっす/うぃーす](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18014/5010). It's rare but used nationwide, especially by otaku-ish people. You should not use it outside of very casual settings.